# VB.NET mySQL insert command

Tags: mysql, vb.net

this is my DB :
[image]

I am trying to add to my presence table a new row, here it is : 
I don't get any VB errors nor mySQL errors, so I guess I am missing something important to add here.

Can you guys help me please ? Thanks in advance

```
  Try

        Dim SqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO presence(id_presence,id,hours,date) " & _
            "SELECT DISTINCT @Id_presence,@Id,@Hours,@Date FROM presence"

        Using con = New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = accounts; Uid=root; Pwd = password")
            Using SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, con)
                con.Open()
                SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Id_presence", TextBox1.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Id", TextBox2.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Hours", TextBox3.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Date", TextBox4.Text))
            End Using


        End Using




    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate an existing record here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for adding a NEW record to your table should be

```
 Dim SqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO presence(id_presence,id,hours,date) " & _
                          "VALUES (@Id_presence,@Id,@Hours,@Date)"
```

And, of course, every command should be executed otherwise it is just a uselese lines of code.
You are missing this line after the creation of the parameters.

```
  SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

From your image is not possible to be sure, but if the idpresence is an AUTOINCREMENT field, then you should not try to set its value with your command and parameter but let the database do it for you. (Duplicate keys problems could arise if more than one user inserts records at the same time)

As a last thing, your parameters' type are not specified so they don't match the underlying datatable schema. You could use AddWithValue and converting the input textbox values to the correct database type

```
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_presence", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text))
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text))
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text))
```

Comment: Indeed my id_presence has auto-increment.
Thanks a lot, you're the vb & mySQL God.

Answer (score 1):

Add `SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to execute it before End Using

Example

```
Public Sub CreateCommand(ByVal queryString As String, _
  ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using 
End Sub
```

reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2