# VB.NET Conversion from type `Byte()` to type 'String is not Valid''

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to display count of users in a label but sadly an error showing Conversion from type `Byte()` to type 'String is not Valid''

```
 Dim Number2 As String = "SELECT CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.number) IS NULL
                                            THEN '0'
                                            WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.number) = ''
                                            THEN '0'
                                            ELSE SUM(t.number)    END  as 'Total'
                                FROM types_of_learners t JOIN
                                blh_location blhloc
                                ON t.blh_location_userid=blhloc.blh_id
                                WHERE t.date_submitted >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 0 day) 
                                AND t.tol='Associations'
                                AND blhloc.blh_barangay='" & locationtxt.Text & "'"
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(Number2, mycon)
        dt = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        txtNo2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Total")
```

When I try changing string to Integer a different show-up this is what it said
'Conversion from string "SELECT CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(DI" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Comment: Do you really need that GROUP_CONCAT function? You can SUM avoiding null values with COALESCE

Comment: check what datatype is set to Number column in database ??

Comment: Incidentally, you should get into the good habit of using SQL parameters for values like `locationtxt.Text`. Otherwise, it will break if someone accidentally types an apostrophe, or someone could deliberately break into the database with an [SQL injection attack](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/). There's an example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23041263/1115360).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using

```
txtNo2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Total").ToString()
```

Comment: the code words but its displaying "System.Byte[]" on textbox

Comment: Its okay now I try this one "Allow User Variables=True;Respect Binary flags=false" https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/695619/mysql-data-display-system-byte-in-datatable-during

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that GROUP_CONCAT that force you to a string expression because SUM by itself ignores NULL values

```
Dim Number2 As String = "SELECT SUM(t.number) as 'Total'
                         .....
```

And, as a side note. This line

```
    AND blhloc.blh_barangay='" & locationtxt.Text & "'"
```

is a well known security problem because it allows the execution of an SQL Injection attack. Use always parameters as in

```
    .....
    AND blhloc.blh_barangay=@loc"

    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(Number2, mycon)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@loc", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = locationtxt.Text
    dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    txtNo2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Total")
```